# How create new dataframe of model predictions using fitted() to run existing lm/lmer model with interaction?

Tags: r, dataframe, lme4

For lack of better phrasing: I need to create a new dataframe from an existing dataframe to run an lm/lmer model to get the model predictions.

Suppose I have:

```
    x <- as.numeric(rep(1:6,5))
    y <- as.numeric(rep(1:5,6))
    int1 <- factor(rep(c("a","b"),15))
    int2 <- factor(rep(c("11","12","13"),10))
    g <- rep(c("f","m"),15)
    df <- data.frame(x,y,int1,int2,g)

    head(df)
    #  x y int1 int2 g
    #1 1 1    a   11 f
    #2 2 2    b   12 m
    #3 3 3    a   13 f
    #4 4 4    b   11 m
    #5 5 5    a   12 f
    #6 6 1    b   13 m

    library(lme4)
    mod <- lmer(y ~ x + int1*int2 + (1|g), data=df) #model I need

    #OR:   
    #mod <- lm(y ~ x + int1*int2, data=df) #might be enough, don't need                    
    #random effects in new df.
```

Now I need to create a new df to run the fitted model on to get predictions. 
I only care about the interaction terms (2x3 interaction), but apparently, the new df needs to have all fixed effects, otherwise it throws an error. The random effects are left out.
The new df has standard errors and confidence interval boundaries.

It should look roughly like this:

```
    > foo                       
     int1/int2fit     se    lwr     upr 
        11  68.86   2.03    64.91   72.86   #main effect
        12  43.44   5.78    32.50   55.10   #main effect
        13  38.77   4.14    31.12   47.19   #main effect
        a   36.81   5.87    26.05   48.72   #main effect
        b   34.58   3.59    27.55   41.71   #main effect
        11a 28.04   4.40    19.87   37.31   #interaction term
        11b 32.69   3.92    25.28   40.48   #interaction term
        11c more numbers    …   …           #interaction term
        12a …   …   …   …                   #interaction term
        12b …   …   …   …                   #interaction term
        12c …   …   …   …                   #interaction term
        13a …   …   …   …                   #interaction term
        13b …   …   …   …                   #interaction term
        13c …   …   …   …                   #interaction term
```

The code I used is below. It does not work, the errors are in the first line.

```
    newdata <- data.frame(int1 = levels(df$int1), int2 = levels(df$int2),         
    x = range(df$x)) #wrong. How change it?
    fitmod = fitted(mod, newdata = newdata, re_formula = NA, summary =  
                    T)*100       #convert to %
    colnames(fitmod) = c('fit', 'se', 'lwr', 'upr')
    foo = cbind(newdata, fitmod)
```

Creating an additional column combining int1 and int2 also does not work.
If the model had only a single predictor that was a factor, it would be:

```
    newdata <- data.frame(int1 = levels(df$int1))
```

How do I set up this df correctly so I get all the correct coefs? 
Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest to use `modelr`:

```
newdat <- modelr::data_grid(df, .model = mod)
newdat$pr <- predict(mod, newdat)
```

But it sounds like maybe you're after using `emmeans` instead?

```
emmeans::emmeans(mod, ~int1:int2)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll try it! I'm actually using package `brms` for Bayesian regression, but I'll think it's exactly the same with `lme4`.

Comment: I tried your suggestion with `modelr`, but `newdat` is a `data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows`

Comment: Then you need to manually specify the columns you need in data_grid

Comment: But emmeans seemed to work great! Thanks again!
One question though: Given that this is a Bayesian analysis and I might need to extract MCMC chains in a similar way, there is no way to do this with emmeans, is there? In my code above, all that needs to be changed is `summary = F` (from `(summary = T)*100`), apparently, and the chains are extracted instead of the summary.

Comment: Saw your response just now, great, I'll try it as well.